# How to Stop an Android Bound Service when the app is killed?

Tags: android, android-service

I have created a Service to implement a Music Player functionality and i am binding to the service.

Everything is working fine, the only problem is that when I kill my app while the song is playing, it kills the app, the notification also goes away but the song keeps on playing in the background without any notification, and to stop the audio, the app needs to be launched again.
But when i clear all tasks (kill all the apps) while the while a song is playing, it kills the app as well as the Song, which is correct.

I need a solution to stop the Audio when only my App is killed.

I have implemented **onTaskRemoved()** callback but the control doesn't always come there.

Can anyone help me here ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your service foreground? How do you start the song?
Also check onStartCommand return flag: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service#onStartCommand(android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int)

Comment: @IvanShafran yes, my service is foreground. I am not using startService, i am using bindService, so onStartCommand won't be called.

Comment: I am a bit confused. You can bind to service only if it is running, as far as I know. So onStartCommand should be called at some point in time. Another point is using foreground service. If service is foreground notification stays after killing the app. I would suggest debugging service callbacks carefully. Also, it would be much easier to help you, if you provide code snippets

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the app is not disconnected fully from the service, 
Try to call unbindService().
If your client is still bound to a service when your app destroys the client, destruction causes the client to unbind. It is better to practice to unbind the client as soon as it is done interacting with the service. Doing so allows the idle service to shut down. 
Try looking at **Managing the lifecycle of a bound service**
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services#Lifecycle